# Include new line character in value attribute of Liferay search container

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have the following line of code of search container.
I want to include a new line between the two values that I want to display..

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='Employee Name'
      value='<%=String.valueOf(search.getEmpFname()) +  String.valueOf(search.getEmpLname()) +"\n" + String.valueOf(search.getEmpTitle()) %>'
      href="" >
```

The reason I want it this way is that I want all these values in one box each row.

So how should I format the above code so that I have:

```
 String.valueOf(search.getEmpFname()) +  String.valueOf(search.getEmpLname())
```

on one line and

```
  String.valueOf(search.getEmpTitle())
```

on the next line of the same row.

Comment: You can try using `<br>` tag instead of `"\n"` like this ` String.valueOf(search.getEmpLname()) +"<br>" + String.valueOf(search.getEmpTitle()` or use `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp` tag instead of `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text` tag.

Comment: @Rasabihari Kumar:
convert this as an answer so I can accpet it.. Thanks for the suggestion. It worked!!

Comment: U r welcome. converted the comment into an answer with an additional detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Converting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514999/include-new-line-character-in-value-attribute-of-liferay-search-container#comment23714140_16514999) as an answer:***

You can try using `<br>` tag instead of `"\n"` like this:

```
String.valueOf(search.getEmpLname()) + "<br>" + String.valueOf(search.getEmpTitle()`
```

or you can use `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp` tag instead of `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text` tag

or else use the tag as following:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='Employee Name' href="">
   <%=String.valueOf(search.getEmpFname()) + String.valueOf(search.getEmpLname()) %>
   <br>
   <%= String.valueOf(search.getEmpTitle()) %>
</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>*emphasized text**emphasized text*
```